# How to set input to a Nattable dynamically?

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I have a NatTable which will populate default data when a View is opened. 
I have to change the contents of NatTable and add more columns or remove columns to the NatTable based upon the selection of items from a combobox widget present in the same view. 
How will I able to dynamically set the input to a NatTable and further add more columns or remove some of the columns? Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the NatTable Examples application from here: 
https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=examples_application

Then open Tutorial Examples -> Data -> ChangeDataProviderExample

That example should show in detail how your requirement can be achieved.